# Error displaying data - scope - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with displaying data using AngularJS.

So my application is based on AngularJS and CodeIgniter 3.

I've created a validation in CodeIgniter written in the form, everything works.

```
public function create()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('','');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'login' , 'Imię' , 'required|min_length[3]' );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'email' , 'Email' , 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]' );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'password' , 'Hasło' , 'required|matches[passconf]' );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'passconf' , 'Powtórz hasło' , 'required|matches[password]' );

        if ( $this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $user = $this->input->post('user');
            unset($user['passconf']);
            $user['password'] = crypt($user['password'], config_item('encryption_key'));
            $this->Users_model->create($user);
        }

        else
        {
            $errors['login'] = form_error( 'login' );
            $errors['email'] = form_error( 'email' );
            $errors['password'] = form_error( 'password' );
            $errors['passconf'] = form_error( 'passconf' );
            echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $errors ) . '}';
        }


    }
```

On the AngularJS side, I wanted errory to appear.

```
controllersAdmin.controller('userCreate', function( $scope, $http, $timeout ){

  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.user.role = 'user';

   $scope.createUser = function( user ){
    $http({
      method: 'POST', url: 'api/admin/users/create/' , 
      data: {
        user : user,
        login : user.login,
        email : user.email,
        password : user.password,
        passconf : user.passconf
      }}
      ).then(function ( errors ){ 

        if ( errors )
      {
        $scope.errors = errors;
      }
      else
      {
        $scope.success = true;
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.success = false;
          $scope.user = {};
        } , 3000 );
      }


   },function (error){
      console.log('Blad we wczytywaniu danych');
   });
   }
});
```

I created `$scope.errors = errors;`

When I display it with `{{errors}}` - data is displayed.

```
{"data":{"records":{"login":"Pole Imię jest wymagane.","email":"Pole Email jest wymagane.","password":"Pole Hasło jest wymagane.","passconf":"Pole Powtórz hasło jest wymagane."}},"status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"api/admin/users/create/","data":{"user":{"role":"user"}},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"OK","xhrStatus":"complete"}
```

However, when I give `{{errors.login}}`, the data is not displayed. Can I count on little help?

Comment: Is the a login property on the errors object? Could you post the what is coming back?

Comment: @Mickers {{errors}} displays such data

{"data":{"records":{"login":"Pole Imię jest wymagane.","email":"Pole Email jest wymagane.","password":"Pole Hasło jest wymagane.","passconf":"Pole Powtórz hasło jest wymagane."}},"status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"api/admin/users/create/","data":{"user":{"role":"user"}},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"OK","xhrStatus":"complete"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's your problem. Login is not a property of the errors object but a sub property. It should be errors.data.records.login.